# how to write java close connection?

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, try-catch

I have more than 2 classes that implemented the connection separately using  try-catch, however when I tried to close the connection in the main it didn't work since it has a scope in the try-catch. 
My question is how do I close the connection while using the try-catch block?

Here is my code for one of my classes

```
String query="INSERT INTO branch (branch_Num , Street, Nieghbourhood,city) VALUES (?, ?,?, ?)";

try{
    PreparedStatement ps;
    String f="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/coffeeZone";
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(f, "coffee", "1234"); 
    ps=connection.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, bno);
    ps.setString(2, strt);
    ps.setString(3, nbh);
    ps.setString(4, ci);
    if (ps.executeUpdate()>0){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Complete! a new branch is added !");
    }else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "");
    }       
 } catch (SQLException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,ex);
 }
```

Comment: Why won't you close it inside the `try` block ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to do this in `finally` block, so that it's executed no matter if the operation was successful or not (an exception was thrown):

```
connection.close();
```

Or easier - use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). Then writing:

```
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(f, "coffee", "1234")) {
    ...
}
```

Then you won't have to worry about closing the resource.

Answer (score 3):

Since java version 1.7 you can use **try-with-resources** as following:

```
    String f = ...
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(f, "coffee", "1234")) {
        ...
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ...
    }
```

and it will be closed automatically by java.